# AWS Direct Connect Public Virtual Interfaces Pricing

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking

I want to use an AWS Direct Connect public Virtual Interface (VIF) to carry an IPsec VPN from my VPC to another gateway.

- Any idea on the pricing for the data transfer over VPN?

Answer (score 0):

Traffic sent over Direct Connect is subject to Data Transfer pricing for **outbound** traffic.

See the **AWS Direct Connect data transfer** section on: [AWS Direct Connect Pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/directconnect/pricing/)